# What method is implemented for drift compensation in the gyroscope?

Tags: gyroscope, google-project-tango, tango, drift

I am trying to access the physical un-calibrated gyroscope sensor. But I am unable to. Since I can only access the calibrated one, I want to know what method is used for drift compensation in the gyroscope sensor used in the Tango Device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows exactly what Tango uses for drift compensation, my own guess would be that they are heavily reliant on [Structure From Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion) techniques.  If you're asking how to calibrate an already calibrated gyro (calibration quality is a different issue :-) ), that's a topic for an entire stack overflow site, not a single answer  :-)   And it would leave you battling for computation resources with Tango - if you want to experiment, any phone with 3DOF attitude sensing and a decent camera is a good starting platform for learning about this, but be warned - it's really complex - much nicer to have it packaged and take what you get.

Comment: Thanks Mark! The Tango device boasts of drift compensation and I wanted to know how they did it.